# Fetching multiple records from same table

Tags: mysql, drupal

How can i write a mysql query to fetch the same field. My table data is as follows.

```
Nid title language tid
 1   aa    en       1
 2   aa    ar       1
 3   bb    en       2
 4   bb    ar       2
```

Now i want to show the fields like nid,  title, english nid , arabic nid.

Desired output:

```
 Nid Title  engilsh nid Arabic nid
  1    aa    1             2
  2    bb    3             4
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: Updated the question. I don't know this is possible or not. But i want the output like that.

Comment: Your first column in desired output doesn't make any sense. It doesn't correspond to values in sample data for bb title. You either don't need it as `nid` or it just line/row number that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT title,
       MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'en' THEN nid END) english_nid, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN language = 'ar' THEN nid END) arabic_nid
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY title
```

Output:

```
| TITLE | ENGLISH_NID | ARABIC_NID |
------------------------------------
|    aa |           1 |          2 |
|    bb |           3 |          4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48f6/4)** demo